# Is it customary to express heat loss as a negative number?

Tags: energy, heat

In my chemistry class, we had a problem akin to the following:

> If an object with mass bla and specific heat bla is placed into a bla g calorimeter with an initial temperature of bla and a specific heat of bla, and the temperature of the calorimeter rises to bla at the end of the experiment, **how much heat was lost by the object?**

I performed the calculations and got an answer of, let's say, $8 J$. When I submitted this answer, I was told that it was wrong, and the correct answer would have been $-8 J$. Wouldn't this response to the above question mean that the object *gained* heat?

Comment: Sign conventions have always been a bit of an issue in chemistry, especially in introductory courses. I agree with your interpretation in this case, but what might have been meant by the question was to state the heat change of the object, in which case -8J follows standard convention.

Comment: It is better to say it as a convention, than saying it as a customary. It is convention that, one hand we consider as right, and the other as left. One may assume the vice versa case. It would not be wrong.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is whether I'm right or wrong.

Comment: Note that physicists and chemists use different sign conventions for work, and I've seen some variation in the convention for heat, too.

Comment: In cases such as these, I think it can be useful to explicitly write out that "$8 J$ of heat is released", or "considering the convention that negative energies correspond to heat release, the energy involved in the process is $-8 J$" to cut through any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your assumptions are correct**, and from the wording of the question, the "correct" answer doesn't make sense, unless like you said, the object gained heat, which is possible; people have negative profits all the time. Sign conventions are not flawed in chemistry, but you just have to be careful when wording a question. To answer the title of your question, yes it is not only customary, it is *necessary* to express heat loss as a negative number, but the question still has to be phrased correctly--using the term "lost" serves as a negation in this use of language, the same way the unary operator in -1 serves as negation for a number. If heat loss were not expressed negatively, it wouldn't make sense because the system of an exothermic reaction must lose energy for its surroundings to gain it.